# cloumn not found error on addMedia method

Tags: php, laravel, media-library

I have installed **media library** by **Spatie** for **laravel** and there is a problem.
when using **addMedia** method and my model name is **Post** an following error occurs:

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'post_id' in 'field list' ...
```

I have test with other models and there is no problem.
Actually there is no **post_id** field and no need to be

here is the code:

```
$post = new \App\Post();
$post->userId = 1;
$post->title = "Test title";
$post->save();

$post->addMedia($request->file('image'))
        ->toMediaCollection('default');
```

Comment: do you have post_id in your database table?

Comment: I think you are using relationship somewhere in your code, is it correct?

Comment: Can you show the code that throws the error?

Comment: @RouhollahMazarei thanks for your answer, yeah I have 'post_id' but in another table. There is no relation between that table and the "media" table

Comment: @Christoffer I had edit the question.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer:

there was another model with name **Media** that seems to conflict with the original one from the library